# Can I List all items that contain these values on my DynamoDB table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that holds items with the following structure:

```
{
  "applicationName": { //PARTITION KEY
    "S": "FOO_APP"
  },
  "requestId": { // SORT KEY
    "S": "zzz/yyy/xxx/58C28B6"
  },
  "creationTime": {
    "N": "1636332219136"
  },
  "requestStatus": {
    "S": "DENIED"
  },
  "resolver": {
    "S": "SOMEONE"
  }
}
```

In DynamoDB, can I query this table to *List* all items that match the provided values for `applicationName`, `requestStatus` and, `resolver`?

In other words, how can I list all items that match:

- applicationName = 'FOO',
- requestStatus = 'DENIED', and
- resolver = 'SOMEONE'

With this table design, do I need GSIs? Can I do a Query or would it be a Scan?

What is the most cost-effective, efficient way of accomplishing this task?

I'm using Java's [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another attribute that combines the values you're querying for, like this:

```
GSI1PK: <applicationName>#<requestStatus>#<resolver>
```

Then you define a Global Secondary Index (`GSI1`) with the Partition Key as `GSI1PK` and the sort key like your current sort key `requestId`.

Whenever you want to find all requests that match these three conditions, you build your search thing and query the global secondary index:

```
Query @GSI1
Partition Key = FOO_APP#DENIED#SOMEONE
```

That will yield all requests that match the combination of criteria. This kind of denormalization is common in NoSQL databases like DynamoDB.

Comment: I like this. I do have a follow up question, though: How would I go about if I wanted to support different access patterns? Say, what if I wanted to list items by applicationName and just one of the two other attributes, but not both?

Comment: You'd have to decide on either of the combinations or set up a GSI per Access Pattern. DynamoDB isn't optimized to serve a huge variety of dynamic access patterns. You need to know them in advance and design your database to serve a specific set of them.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to query this schema as your sort key - *requestId* is not in criteria. That means, your query will fail. For a better schema design, you should have a sort key in such a way which can help you narrow down result set obtained by just querying on PartitionKey.

So for solution, you will have to create new index as following:

> applicationName -> Partition Key
>
> requestStatus -> Sort Key
>
> resolver

Then you can query with keyConditionExpression on *applicationName* and *requestStatus* with filterExpression on *resolver*.

Comment: This will work, but you're consuming a lot more Read Capacity Units than necessary, because the filter expression is only applied after the items have been read from the table.